# Inconsistency for "cancel" button on question delete popup

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, capitalization

Trying to delete your own question when it has answers shows me a popup:

> [image: delete]

The "cancel" link (button?) is written in lower case. In the same time while editing the "Cancel" link is started from the capital letter:

> [image: edit]

Could this inconsistency please be fixed.