# "Cancel" not capitalized in the self-answer to your own question field

Tags: bug, status-completed, capitalization

When you press the button to self-answer your question, you get a pop-up that looks like this:

[image]

Notice how *cancel* is not capitalized.

Stacks requires the menu items be in sentence case, so this should be "Cancel" instead of "cancel".

Comment: [Earlier request asking for the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328047/377214), but only mentions one specific type of popup (this one is generalized to all popups).

Comment: We'll look at picking this up part of our standard bug duty. Thanks for reporting it! @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog - I've added a note about that one but it's also not a Stacks dialogue yet (this one probably isn't, either, for that matter), so the whole thing needs to be updated eventually. Also, the bug report didn't catch all the issues - "Delete Question" needs to be "Delete question" and "Save Edits" needs to be "Save edits"

Comment: Nitpicking... seriously how big of an issue is this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If we said that every time we found a mistake, Stack Exchange would be in a horrible place right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button label is now Capitalized.

And for what it's worth, the module’s styles have also been brought up to date with our Stacks framework.

---

> "It's just one letter"!
> But what is a doc but a
> multitude of letters

(number of syllables on the last line intentional, please don’t change)

Comment: *[Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)*. What part?